# How to display differences in files via git log

Tags: git

Is it possible to display differences in commits using `git log`? In addition to graph I also need diff info but the best I can get is:

```
git log --graph --name-status --oneline --decorate
```

But that gives me only info if file was modified or not, but I'm also interested in what modifications been made. Is it possible via `git log` or other command?

Comment: `git log --patch` and without `--name-status`?

Comment: this is excellent, could you please make it into an answer, I will be happy to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `--name-status` and add `--patch` option.

It will display the tree together with patches.

You can also remove `--oneline` or add `--pretty=raw` to see more things in the commits.

Finally you can use `gitk` tool to view the tree (including the patches) in GUI.